# How to use iterations and conditions activities in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have 10000 file in adls folder
All filename I'm getting by using the get metadata activity and pass it to the for each loop in the first execution it should pick 1000 files and merge it to one single file in the next run it should pick another set of files 2000 after getting the total file count.Is their any work around in the data factory to run the set of files in the batches ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Iterate and merge the batch of 1000 files you need to first group the file names/ path in a different file that need to be processed in a batch. the using list of files option in ADF copy activity merge the files.

**Follow the below process (I tried with total 5 files by grouping 2 files):**

1. Take a dataflow activity add new dataflow.

- In source add the dataset where all 10000 files are located and in source options set **Wildcard paths** as `*` and with **Column to store file name** add file name column in data set.
  [image]
  [image]
- Take an aggregate transformation and in group by select filename column and in aggregates perform any aggregate task on any column.
  [image]
  [image]
- Then take a derived column activity to remove the first backslash from file name/path with expression `dropLeft(filename,1)`
  [image]
- In sink add dataset where you need to store these files with unchecking the **First row as header**
  [image]
- Set **Skip line count** to 1
  [image]
- In setting set the **File name option** as `Pattern` and **Pattern** as `file[1]000.csv`
  [image]
- In mapping select only **filename** column.
  [image]
- In Optimize set the partitioning as dynamic range based on filename column and set the no of partotion in yoyr case 10.
  [image]

**Output of the is as below:**

[image]

2. Then use get metadata activity to get the list of files where each file contains list of files that need to be merged.
   [image]
3. Then pass these files to foreach activity to loop over `@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems`.
   [image]
4. In for each activity take copy activity

- Set **File path type** is **List of files** in Path to files list set the dynamic way to get the files.
  [image]
- In copy activity dataset add the data set that con tail files need to be merged.
  [image]
- Add sink and set **copy behavior** as **merge files**.
  [image]

**Output:**

***It will merge all the list of files which we got from dataflow***
[image]

Comment: We can't create batch on size with this approach.

Comment: @heenashaikh It seems like you are coming with new requirement for that please post new question so other community members can also help you.